# Flutter - Scaffold with Appbar and listview - breaking with Expanded

Tags: flutter

I have an issue with Scaffold. I have an AppBar with text and a button. The body hosts a ListView.builder. Inside the ListView is a container and a number of TextButton Widgets.

The Text part of the TextButton can be wide, and causes the warning bar to appear. So, I wrapped in an Expanded widget to wrap it.

This results in an error...

> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout(): RenderFlex
> children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are
> unbounded.
>
> When a row is in a parent that does not provide a finite width
> constraint, for example if it is in a horizontal scrollable, it will
> try to shrink-wrap its children along the horizontal axis. Setting a
> flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to
> expand to fill the remaining space in the horizontal direction. These
> two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap
> its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
>
> Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using
> FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather
> than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
> themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would
> otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to
> shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
> constraints provided by the parent.

and also the contents of my AppBar disappear, and I can no longer click the back arrow.

Here is the scaffold to build the page...

```
late StateSetter _setState;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return buildSubFormPage();

}


Widget buildSubPage() {

  return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (bContext, StateSetter setBState) {
        _setState = setBState;
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text("My list of items"),
              actions: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 20.0),
                  child: openSubFormItem(
                      widget.field, 0,
                      "+ Add new", null),
                )
              ],
            ),
            body: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              //shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: subFormItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  //width: screenWidth,
                  child: openSubFormItem(
                      widget.field, index, "Press Here",
                      subFormItems[index]),

                );
              },

            )

        );
      }
  );
}
```

Here is mostly the content of my openSubFormItem widget.

The building of the button text has been removed, but you can get the idea...

```
Widget openSubFormItem(PendigoFields field, int index, String buttonText, dynamic subFormItem) {

String outputText = "A long string of text, that will surely cause the warning bars if I can't make it wrap properly";

if (buttonText == "+ Add new") {
  outputText = buttonText;
}

return Container(
    //padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
  //width: screenWidth - 30,
    child:
    TextButton(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          // Flexible(
          //   fit : FlexFit.loose,
          //   child: Text(outputText, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
          //     fontSize: 15.0,
          //     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),
          // ),

          Expanded(child: Text(outputText, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 15.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),
          ),

          // Text(outputText, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
          //   fontSize: 15.0,
          //   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),

          // I also have an IconButton here, removed for clarity

       ]
      ),
    )
    decoration: buttonText == "Press Here" ? BoxDecoration(
      
      border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[400]!)),
    )
        : null
);

}
```

How do I get my AppBar to show the AppBar content (and button) and allow my ListView to be able to wrap the text if the text is too long?

Comment: Please provide a minimal full runnable snippet that shows the problem. Your code depends on some external variables.

Comment: Editted. This should now show the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says: unbounded width, this is because the Row parent which is the TextButton does not have a specified width, and when using Expanded, the Row or the Column parent of it must know its constrains.

Give a width to the TextButton.

Also a note, don't create your widgets using methods as this is not recommend from flutter team, use separated widgets instead.

Comment: Ah, understand now. I have put in style: TextButton.styleFrom(fixedSize: Size.fromWidth(screenWidth - 270)). I was thinking it was the AppBar size that I needed. I am not sure what you mean though about not creating widgets from methods. (I am quite new to flutter)

Comment: I mean by not creating widgets from methods that don't create a method that returns a widget, but create a stateless or stateful widget and use it. check this: https://youtu.be/IOyq-eTRhvo